# Angular material auto complete change event not called when component loading?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I used angular material("@angular/material": "7.1.0") auto-complete component and then i used form control instead of ng model, now the problem is, i can't get the auto-complete change event when the component is loading. I was set the value to the auto-complete component on ngOnInint method that time i want to call one method based on the auto-complete value changes.

I have created a code at stackblitz, here is the link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xmnmpy

Answer (score 19):

You must use `optionSelected` event on `<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="onSelectionChange($event)" >`

[Example on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-egyep4?file=src/app/app.component.html)

You must use in html :

```
<form [formGroup]="myGroup">
<mat-form-field>
    <input type="text"
          matInput
          [matAutocomplete]="auto"
          formControlName="identifier">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="onSelectionChange($event)" >
      <mat-option *ngFor="let animal of animals"
            [value]="animal.name">
        {{animal.name}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

And in your ts:

```
  onSelectionChange(event){
    console.log('onSelectionChange called', event.option.value);
  }
```

Hope I helped you, also if you need help be free to ask me!

Answer (score 5):

Well, first of all, you're not using `ngOnInit` at all.

Secondly, `ngModelChange` doesn't work with reactive forms.

You will have to listen to value changes like so:

```
this.myGroup
    .get('identifier').valueChanges.subscribe(value => console.log('Value changes'));
```

This is a standard way of listening to value changes with reactive forms.

Here is your [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tjhcvx?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

Comment: ngModelChange definitely works with ReactiveFormsModule and is super useful if you want to mask values like phone numbers when you might want the formcontrol's value to differ from what you mask and show the user... https://angular-ctqq3d.stackblitz.io

Comment: It didn't in the older versions of Angular.